# Can monsters use weapons they took from player characters via Disarm?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, weapons, disarming

Without necessarily getting into whether or not Disarm is a waste of time or not, if a monster Disarms a PC, (page 271, DMG) can that monster use the weapon if it picks it up?

Example...

A Bandit Captain uses its first Melee Weapon Attack to Disarm a PC of their magic sword...  then a free action to interact with an object to pick up the magic weapon, and its second Melee Weapon Attack to attack the PC with its new toy, the PCs former weapon?

Multiattack is specific to certain weapons sometimes... can monsters use other weapons not listed in its multiattack?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Not an answer but a note - even if they aren't going to use the weapon in an attack, there's still a benefit to taking the weapon - that is, it keeps their enemy from being able to use it!

Answer (score 22):

This is entirely up to the DM.

MM 9 (sidebar Armor, Weapon, and Tool Proficiencies):

> Assume that a creature is proficient with its armor, weapons, and tools. If you swap them out, you decide whether the creature is proficient with its new equipment.

As noted in the comments, the only wrinkle here is attunement. If the weapon requires attunement to unlock certain properties, the monster cannot use those properties for the attack. A Holy Avenger, for example, would just be a regular sword, but a Dagger of Venom would function normally.

As for Multiattack: in cases where it specifies a weapon (e.g. Oni :"...two attacks, either with its claws or its glaive"), RAW would indicate that it cannot use different weapons for Multiattack (and could only instead take the Attack action, making 1 attack). Other monsters (e.g. Cult Fanatic: "two melee weapon attacks") could use Multiattack with any melee weapon they happened to be using.

As for me, I'd likely say that any decently-intelligent humanoid (such as the Bandit Captain in the example) can use any proficient weapon of the same category (ie melee vs ranged) for Multiattack. But that's my personal ruling, not RAW.

Comment: I agree with this answer +1. But you might want to add that if the weapon is an attunement weapon then they won't gain any of the benefits of the weapon for the attack.

Comment: Well, some magic, attunable weapons have flat hit/damage bonuses, and extra effects only when attuned. In those cases, attunement is not required for the hit/damage bonus.

Comment: In other words *read what the magic item does, and apply stats accordingly*